# Simple feedforward neural network does not behave as intended

Tags: algorithm, neural-network

I'm having a hard time figuring out why my feed forward artificial neural networks almost always fail to learn my simple "OR" perceptron:

- 0 or 0 : 0
- 1 or 0 : 1
- 0 or 1 : 1
- 1 or 1 : 1

I tried various network configurations : 1 or 2 hidden layers, 2 to 8 neurons on hidden layers, a bias (value = 1, connected to each hidden neuron and output neuron)

For this example, the network looks like:

```
[1]    [3]
[2]    [4]    [6]
       [5]
```

- input layer : [1] and [2]
- hidden layer : [3] and [4] and [6]
- output layer : [6]

**Notations:**

- Neuron i : [i]
- Weight between [i] and [j] : w(i,j)
- [i] value : v(i)
- [i] error: e(i)
- sig(t) : 1/(1 + e^-t)

**Weights initialization**

Each weight is set to a random value between -0.5 and 0.5

**Input**

v(1) and v(2) are set with random values : 0 or 1

**Propagate value (from left to right) :**

- v(3) = sig(v(1) * w(1,3) + v(2) * w(2,3))
- v(4) = sig(v(1) * w(1,4) + v(2) * w(2,4))
- v(5) = sig(v(1) * w(1,5) + v(2) * w(2,5))
- v(6) = sig(v(3) * w(3,6) + v(4) * w(4,6) + v(5) * w(5,6))

**expected output : 1 if  (v(1) or v(2)) is true, 0 otherwise**

- e(6) = (expected - v(6)) * v(6) * (1 - v(6))

**Propagate error (from right to left)**

- e(3) = e(6) * w(3,6) * v(3) * (1 - v(3))
- e(4) = e(6) * w(4,6) * v(4) * (1 - v(4))
- e(5) = e(6) * w(5,6) * v(5) * (1 - v(5))

**Update weights (learning rate = 1)**

- w(1,3) = w(1,3) + v(1) * e(3)
- w(1,4) = w(1,4) + v(1) * e(4)
- w(1,5) = w(1,5) + v(1) * e(5)
- w(2,3) = w(2,3) + v(2) * e(3)
- w(2,4) = w(2,4) + v(2) * e(4)
- w(2,5) = w(2,5) + v(2) * e(5)
- w(3,6) = w(3,6) + v(3) * e(6)
- w(4,6) = w(4,6) + v(4) * e(6)
- w(5,6) = w(5,6) + v(5) * e(6)

**Do it 300 times and print each result:**

- if v(6) > 0.5, it’s a True
- if v(6) < 0.5, it’s a False
- compare with expected output

After a few epoch, the network almost always return v(6) > 0.9, even for v(1) = v(2) = 0

Sometimes (roughly 1 out of 20 times), it works, the network learned correctly

What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT:**
I found it !

The culprits was :

- e(3) = e(6) * w(3,6) *** v(3) * (1 - v(3))**
- e(4) = e(6) * w(4,6) *** v(4) * (1 - v(4))**
- e(5) = e(6) * w(5,6) *** v(5) * (1 - v(5))**

Which should have been :

- e(3) = e(6) * w(3,6)
- e(4) = e(6) * w(4,6)
- e(5) = e(6) * w(5,6)

Comment: 2 hidden layers? you only need a single neuron to represent an 'OR' (i.e. no hidden layer). So maybe the problem is, that the network is "too large" for this problem? (that will at least slow down convergence) Also your learning rate should not be equal to 1 but <1 (and decrease over time?)

Comment: I tried 2 hidden layers just to see what happen. And I tried to decrease learning rate over time too (with no better results). My guess is either my algorithm or my code have errors. Thank you anyway for the clarification.

Comment: I don't get it, `delta(hidden) = sum(deta(output) * weight(output, hidden)) * (value(hidden)) * (1-(value(hidden)) ` is the fixed formula, how could omitting the last two terms make it work???